# Interbase: conversion error from string ""

Tags: sql, interbase

I'm running IB2009 and I'm trying to count the number of records where a specific field is neither NULL nor empty:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.ID) FROM MYVIEW A
WHERE ((A.VARCHARFIELD1 IS NOT NULL) OR (A.VARCHARFIELD1 <> ''))
```

where MYVIEW is a VIEW, and MYVIEW.ID is an INTEGER, while MYVIEW.VARCHARFIELD1 is a VARCHAR(18).

I'm getting the error message

> Error at line 1, conversion error from string ""

which I don't really understand, since when I drop the COUNT()-function, the query executes nicely. Do anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with using COUNT() in this case.  Although it shouldn't matter you might try dropping all the parentheses in your WHERE clause.  You also might try using COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(A.ID) just to see if it gives you different results.

In any case, based on your description of the intent of the query I don't think that the query is going to do what you intended.  If the query is supposed to return rows where the field is neither NULL nor empty I believe your WHERE clause should be

```
WHERE A.VARCHARFIELD1 IS NOT NULL AND
      A.VARCHARFIELD1 <> ''
```

With the 'OR' in there as originally written I think you'll get back every row in the table where A.VARCHARFIELD1 is NOT NULL, as the "field NOT NULL" predicate will allow in all non-NULL values, and since the two predicates are joined by an OR the second predicate won't matter.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Bob: well, I actually tried COUNT(*), but to no avail. You're quite correct regarding the 'AND'/'OR' though - there should definitely be an 'AND' there in stead. Thanks! (+1) I believe this to be a bug with the way IB handles VIEWs... It works as a charm when executed against a table with identical fields.